# sqlite 3 times out trying to add column

Tags: sqlite

I've got an sqlite 3 database and have tried several PHP interfaces. One table has over 1500 rows and none of the interfaces seem to cope with adding a column to table of this size. I've tried creating a new table with the new column, then copying records from one to the other. Same problem.

For example with phpliteadmin when I execute the add column command I get an empty response from the server (No data received in Chrome, Connection was reset in Firefox).

Just about tearing my hair out over this one - any suggestions how to add the column, either through an interface or through code?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL As Understood By SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) is your friend.

The SQL statement for adding a column is simply

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN foobar CHAR;
```

I assume that the interfaces timeouts because the command issued fails. 1500 rows is nothing, unless they contain large amounts of data.
I would suggest you download your database file (assuming it is on a webserver), then fire up `sqlite3` from a terminal and try to execute the code.